# spark job timing out when trying to save as table on aws emr

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

We have set up a dedicated cluster for our application on AWS.

This is the configuration of the cores ( we have 2 cores)

```
m5.xlarge
4 vCore, 16 GiB memory, EBS only storage
EBS Storage:64 GiB
```

**Current dataset -**

We are trying to run spark job which involves many joins and works with 80 million records
each record with 60 + fields

**Issue we are facing -**

When we trying to save the final dataframe as athena table, its taking more than 1 hour and timing out.

As we are the only one using the cluster, what should be our configuration to ensure that we use all the cluster resources optimally

**Current configuration**

```
Executor Memory : 2G
Dynamic Allocation Enabled : true
Number of Executor Cores : 1
Number of Executors : 8
spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout : 3600
spark.sql.broadcastTimeout : 36000
```

Comment: I had the same problem and it was solved adding more partitions on the final dataframe before writting the table. Are you writting this table on S3? A good starting point is to save 1GB per partition in parquet format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your config some observation -

You are using

> `m5.xlarge` which is having 4 vCore, 16 GiB memory

Executor config

> Number of Executor Cores : 1
> Executor Memory : 2G

So at most 4 executor can spin up, and **memory required by 4 executor is 8**.
So at the end you are not utilizing all the resource.

---

Also as @Shadowtrooper said, save the data in partition (If possible in Parquet format) if you can, it will also save cost when you query in Athena.

Comment: excellent answer, It's very common that users are not using all the cores while doing IO in spark and their job fails or runs for long. When spark fully utilizes the resources, not only is the program fast but also it saves a lot of cloud costs.